# How can I "reload" a buffer that was previously unloaded using `:bd`, such that it will re-appear in `:ls`?

Tags: buffers

Suppose I have unloaded a buffer and deleted it from the buffer list using `:bd`.

Now, it won't show in the buffer list (`:ls`) anymore, unless `!` is specified in the command: `:ls!`

How can I add the unloaded buffer back into the buffer list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command `:bdelete N` tends to be misleading. What it actually does is:

1) free (i.e. unload) the N-th buffer's contents from RAM (while keeping its number, name, options etc.)

2) remove it from the list of "normal" open buffers (i.e. `set nolisted` option)

But, in fact, these two effects could be also independent one from another and there's no matching "bundelete" command to switch both on without other "side-effects". What you can do is

1) `:h bufload()`, `:h bufloaded()`, `:h :bunload` to load/unload the buffer's contents only

2) `:call setbufvar(N, '&buflisted', zero_or_one)` to switch "listed" flag only

3) Edit the buffer which also (obviously) loads it and makes it "listed", e.g. `:edit #N` or `:split #N` etc. However note that `:buffer N` differs in that it *does not* set listed flag (it is explicitly mentioned in `:h :buffer`).

Comment: thank you. Why doesn’t `:edit N` the `#` work? By “open buffer” you mean a loaded buffer present in RAM, so unloading is the same as closing?

Comment: @Shuzheng `edit N` means edit buffer named "N", `edit #N` means edit buffer number N; closing does not always mean unloading: if there's other window showing this buffer, or `set hidden`, or `setlocal bufhide=hidden` then the buffer could still be loaded (it depends on exact command to close it: say, `ZQ` always unloads, but `:quit` respects `'hidden'` option, etc.).

Comment: @Shuzheng Strictly speaking, you can "close" only windows, while buffers are "unloaded". If you unload a buffer, all its windows are closed too; if you close all windows showing the buffer then the buffer **may** be unloaded, but it can also remain loaded. In the latter case it's called "hidden".

Comment: What does “open” mean then? That the buffer is loaded?

Comment: @Shuzheng Well, that's not really a good word, I admit. I rather meant "listed" buffers.

Comment: `#N` doesn't work in my Neovim. `N` match both on buffer name and number, so if the buffer `bar` has number `1`, then both `:bd bar` and `:bd 1` delete it.

Comment: @Shuzheng `#N` is for `:edit` command. Not applicable to `:bdelete` or `:buffer`.

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is set the [`'buflisted'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27buflisted%27) option on the buffer again. So, running `:setlocal buflisted` on the buffer itself would work.

If you don't have the buffer opened, but you have the buffer id, you can use the [`setbufvar()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#setbufvar%28%29) function, using the `&buflisted` syntax to set the value of the option on the buffer.

For example, for buffer 7, you can use:

```
:call setbufvar(7, '&buflisted', 1)
```

You can confirm that it will now show in the `:ls` output after this command is executed.

Answer (score 2):

(In the case where you `:bwipeout`d the buffer, so it's really *gone*.)

By `:edit`ing a file (or `:split`ing it, or any other command that brings it into a window/tabpage), you'll automatically add it to the buffer list.

If you want to add it to the buffer list *without* summoning it up for editing immediately, you have to do a bit of a dance:

```
let bufnr = bufadd('file')
call bufload(bufnr)
```

This loads the buffer after adding it, but it still won't show without `:ls!` because it is unlisted. You can use filbranden's answer to toggle that variable.